# Why do i cannot connect a Windows agent to a Ubuntu hosted Jenkins?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, jenkins

I have these configurations:

[image: Config 1]

[image: Config 2]

But it would still show me

[image: Config 3]

The remote system rejects connection. I'm trying to connect from Windows to Ubuntu using bridge network in Oracle VM for both, and using the front end url as expected by the Websocket option. I'm stuck, i've tried almost everything, every firewall is down on each of the two VMs. Please, help!